# How to place a user control form in a VB.NET form?

Tags: vb.net

I want to be able to show a user control form at the click of a button. I have not been able to show the form with the .show() as I would be able to with a regular form.

**Question: How to place a user control form in a VB.net form?**

I should rephrase the question. how do I show a user control form in a form. I was not completely certain of this worked when I was building my form.

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim MyDialog As New ColorDialog()
        ' Keeps the user from selecting a custom color.
        MyDialog.AllowFullOpen = True
        ' Allows the user to get help. (The default is false.)
        MyDialog.ShowHelp = True
        ' Sets the initial color select to the current text color,
        MyDialog.Color = TextBox1.ForeColor

        ' Update the text box color if the user clicks OK  
        If (MyDialog.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            TextBox1.ForeColor = MyDialog.Color
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim myCoolFile As String = "C:\Users\itpr13266\Desktop\test.txt" '// your file location.
        Dim tempStr As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(myCoolFile) '// read file into a String.
        Dim x As Integer = tempStr.Length - 1 '// get String length, Index based, starting at 0 not 1.
        Dim myArray(x) As String '// create your String Arrays.
        Dim i As Integer = 0 '// Integer used to increase Array #'s.

        For Each myChr As Char In tempStr '// loop thru each each character in the String.
            myArray(i) = myChr '// add values to each String Array.
            i += 1 '// increase count for next Array.
        Next

        For number As Integer = 1 To myArray.Length - 1 Step 1 'loops through the array by 1 and to 1 less the length
            Debug.Write(myArray(number)) 'write the value in the array to the debug window
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        UserControl1.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It is a meaningless question, no such thing exists.  A user control must be place on a form, you can show that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions here. One is to create a new `Form` in your project and have it host the `UserControl`. Then you instantiate the `Form` in your `Button6_Click` method (the code will be similar to the `ColorDialog` code in your `Button1_Click` method). The other solution is to instantiate a placeholder form directly in the `Button6_Click` handler, like so:

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Using UserControl1 As FooUserControl = New FooUserControl()
        Using tmpForm As Form = New Form()
            tmpForm.Width = UserControl1.Width
            tmpForm.Height = UserControl1.Height
            tmpForm.Controls.Add(UserControl1)
            tmpForm.ShowDialog()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Honestly, the first approach is cleaner, and you will have far more control over how your `UserControl` gets presented by leveraging the WinForms Designer for the host form.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting visibility to True before calling

```
UserControl1.Visible = True
```

Comment: No, nothing. The user control is something I created with buttons and other components. Does it have to be placed in a form or can it be shown without a form on its own. I have not used a user form and am not certain if they are the same as a regular form(I am thinking not).

Comment: UserControlHolder.Controls.Add(UserControl1)

Comment: How about a simple example of a userControl that will work. Can you paste the code in some place

Comment: @avanek beats me posting an example. Please take a look at his answer as well. Thanks